# Access closure variable

Tags: javascript, closures

I have a feeling I know the answer to this question, however is there anyway to view the current value of `inside` via console?

```
var test = (function() {
  var inside = 0;
  return function() {
    inside++;
    console.log(inside);
    return inside;
  }
})();
```

Comment: Uhm, isn't that working just fine, the variable is within the scope ?

Comment: Or did you mean outside that IIFE, is so ***no***, that's not possible.

Comment: Yeah outside of the IIFE without executing it.

Answer (score 0):

Just call `test()` and `console.log` will print the value.

Your closure is self invoked but your inner method is just returned so it is never called in your example.

You should use:

```
var test = (function() {
  var inside = 0;
  return function() {
    inside++;
    console.log(inside);
    return inside;
  }
})();

test();//Will print 1
```

So it will create the closure and your `return` statement will put the inner function in the variable `test`. So your `test` became the inner function. Then you need to call it.

Comment: @downvoter care to comment??